# Auto activate Paypal IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

My question is how can i activate IPN without getting in my paypal acount...

Like did in OpenCart, that every one just insert is paypal acount, and the ipn works..

I hope you know what is OpenCart, If not , i think that my question is clear, if not tell me and i will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the parameter "notify_url" in WPS (Buy Now button, etc) source code, or "PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NOTIFYURL" in Express Checkout, for every transaction. Different URLs can be used for different transactions.

This option works if IPN is enabled in paypal profile. It does NOT work if IPN is disabled.

Comment: I did that, but in IPN History (in my paypal acount) i see the IPN message and write there in Status: "Not Activate"

Comment: If the option is not enabled I'm not sure if PayPal page shows you IPN history, and I won't be surprised if it doesn't. Check your IPN listener to see if you got the message. Out of curiosity, you have access to the PayPal IPN page, why don't you just turn it on?

Comment: First, its shows the message even when IPN is off, but in status wrote "Not Activate", i will check, about your other question, i need it to be dynamicly, like opencart did...

Comment: The message dosent get to the IPN listener when the IPN is off, even if set notify_url, any ideas?

Comment: What payment product are you using? Buy now button, express checkout or anything else?

Comment: Use notify_url then. It should work with different urls each time, and as far as I remember this parameter works even with IPN turned off in the profile settings, but it'd be helpful to do some testing.

Comment: i test it, its dosent send the message

Comment: Sorry my mistake, on _xclick its send the message, do you know if in _cart its also supposu to send even when IPN is off?

Comment: Very sorry, just tested and found when IPN is disabled in profile, EC and WPS will not send IPN even if notify URL is specified. There must be a change on this as I remember very clearly it worked for me at the beginning of the year.

Comment: Good thing is, when IPN is enabled in profile, different notify URL can be used for each transaction.